# Unclear points on projection type and selection of distance metric in feature extraction for a set of scenarios

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, pattern-recognition

The following is an example from a book (An Introduction to Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by P. Fieguth, page 85) on feature extraction and selection. Please consider the following figure.

[image]

I have the following questions:

Q1- Why in Scenario IV will the applicable distance metric in 3D be "very non-Euclidean"? The points in Scenario IV are also in a 3D space for which an Euclidian distance metric is valid in my opinion.

Q2-Why will feature projection to 2D be linear for Scenario 1?

Q3- Why is there only one meaningful feature direction for Scenario 1?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I edited the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1 - in Scenario IV, the data clusters are not linearly separable in 3d, but presumably would be once projected onto the 2d manifold (the manifold assumption or manifold hypothesis). So learning the manifold and then projecting onto that would give better results, and this projection is non-Euclidean.

A2 - If you project all the points onto the y1-y3 plane they are linearly separable. In fact you could project them just onto 1D y3 line and they would still be linearly separable.

A3 - see A2 - you can separate the data clusters using only y3 component.
hth.

Comment: comment for A1: projection and distance metric are different things. My question was not why the needed projection is nonlinear (the fact that the needed projection is nonlinear is clear). It was why the needed distance metric also needs to be non-Euclidian. In a nonlinear projection, you can still use an Euclidean distance metric, no?

Comment: Fair enough. I would lump tend to projection and distance into a single entity but it's equally fair to say that they are separate. I could imagine that a huge number of arbitrary transformations to project data (i.e. manifold learning) would fall into this case, and the final distance metric could still be Euclidean.